# (C#) The WinForm designer is constantly generating "SetChildIndex" codes on derived forms. how do i prevent this?

Tags: c#, winforms, designer

I have a base form with a panel in it. When I inherit in another form, vs constantly adds "SetChildIndex" codes to the designer.cs file. The "btnexcel" control belongs to the base form. I added the others in derived form. How can I prevent these codes from being generated?

[image: The picture belongs to the upper class.]

Comment: You have 3 options: 1) Set the Access Modifier of the Controls in the base Form to `Protected`, so you can modify the Z-Order index using `BringToFront` / `SendToBack` in the Designer of the derived Forms 2) Redefine the Z-Oder in code, calling `BringToFront()` / `SendToBack()` as needed, after `OnHandleCreated()` 3) Write a custom CodeDomSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

It only happens when the `Modifiers` of the button on the base form is set to protected or public. In this case you can modify the control at design-time in the derived form.

If you are interested to add controls to the panel of the base form, then the panel modifier should be protected or public. Then if you want to prevent modifying the existing children of the panel, set their modifiers to private. In this case, when you select one of those private children in designer in the derived form, a small lock icon [image] appear on top-left of the control which shows you cannot modify it.

To learn more about access modifiers in visual inheritance see:

- [How to: Inherit Forms Using the Inheritance Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-inherit-forms-using-the-inheritance-picker-dialog-box?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [Add a button that inheritors of the base form can modify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/walkthrough-demonstrating-visual-inheritance?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#add-a-button-that-inheritors-of-the-base-form-can-modify)
- [Add a button that cannot be modified by inheritors of the base form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/walkthrough-demonstrating-visual-inheritance?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#add-a-button-that-cannot-be-modified-by-inheritors-of-the-base-form)